# Running Apache Nutch in windows 7

Tags: nutch

i am trying to run Nutch with Cygwin. I am having problems with crawling the content

My comment is

$ bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5

Response is

**cygpath: can't convert empty path

**InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the Gora storage class.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-user\mapred\staging\user1249593824.staging to 0700****

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:50)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:233)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:136)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)
```

Help me on this.

Comment: check your config against [http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on this before 2 days. Here's the solution that i followed

1. Download http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2
2. Replace (nutch-directory)/lib/hadoop-core-1.2.0.jar with the downloaded file renaming it with the same name.

That's it.

Comment: If the Answer is correct, accept the answer and put an upvote. Glad, it worked for you.